# How to get my controller web api?

Tags: c#, jquery

Function get in client side jquery coding
here i get an error of not found 404 (the Userscontroller)

```
function GetUserLoginDetails() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#logInBtn').click(function (e) {
            var uri = 'api/Users'
            var userName = $('#_loginUsername').val();
            var password = $('#_logInpassword').val();

            $.getJSON(uri + '/' + userName + '/' + password)
                .done(function (data) {
                    $('#_loginUsername').text(formatItem(data));
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                    $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
                });
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    })
}
```

web api config  to the users controller

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Users",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { userName = RouteParameter.Optional, password = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

My controller that i cant reach my error on client side is "not found" 404

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetUser")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string userName , string password)
  {
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          var result = UsersHandler.GetUser(userName, password);
          return Ok();
        }
     return NotFound();
}
```

this is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:56267/api/Users/GetUser/Get',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(userName, password),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error in Operation');
            }
```

Comment: Can you add what server side technique you are using? That would probably help to clarify your problem

Comment: What do you mean by server side technique ?

Comment: I assume you are not only using jQuery. Where do you sending the  AJAX request? What programming language is used for the controller? Is the URI correctly build up?

Comment: programming language is C#
Im thinking my uri is correct not sure
and im using getJSON function found getjson example

Comment: I add my ajax request

Comment: `ActionName` is for MVC, not Web API. You want `RouteAttribute`. Also there is no sense in mix/matching between `RouteAttribute` and mapping using `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`, pick one or the other. Finally your `RouteAttribute` value is the URL (and optional parameters), the method name means nothing so do not include it in the URL.